# Extracting all YouTube channel subscribers using API v3

Tags: youtube-api

Using the youtube data api version 3 I download subscribers using a query similar to this:

```
v3.channels().\
list(part=parts,mySubscribers=True,
     maxResults=50, pageToken=nextPageToken).execute()
```

I never manage to download more than 70,000 results in total. This result is despite there being many more results available as reported on the channels' page.

For example one channel has over 2 million subscribers so I am retrieving only a small subset of the total.

Is this a limit enforced by Google? Is it possible to extract more?

Comment: I have the same question, getting a list of public subscribers via API. Were you able to get this to work?